# Play multiple audio files with gst pipeline

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I am using gst library to play multiple audio files and I have a problem:

> Error: Internal data flow error

This is my code (without other demuxer and sink init):

```
GstElement *elm1, *elm2;

elm1  = gst_element_factory_make ("filesrc", "file1.ogg");
elm2  = gst_element_factory_make ("filesrc", "file2.ogg");

g_object_set (G_OBJECT (elm1), "location", "file1.ogg", NULL);
g_object_set (G_OBJECT (elm2), "location", "file2.ogg", NULL);

GstBus *bus;

bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus (GST_PIPELINE (pipeline));
bus_watch_id = gst_bus_add_watch (bus, bus_call, loop);
gst_object_unref (bus);

gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), elm1, elm2, demuxer, sink, NULL);

gst_element_link_many (elm1, elm2, demuxer);

g_signal_connect (demuxer, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (on_pad_added), sink);
gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
```

Did I make something wrong?

Comment: do you want to play these file one after the other or simultaneously ? the above code is wrong since pads cannot be connected.

Comment: I would like to play these files one after the other, not simultaneously. why pads cannot be connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to listen for EOS for file-1 and then change the filesrc to file-2.

the following answer should help you -

'[GStreamer dynamically change the filesrc location of a pipeline- No sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398383/gstreamer-dynamically-change-the-filesrc-location-of-a-pipeline-no-sound)'